# How to create multitasking video activity like new youtube App?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, youtube

Anyone has any idea how can i create a multitask video activity ot fragment like new youtube.

Can any body tell me the correct procedure to do this.

How do I achieve this type of feature with visual effect.

Answer (score 1):

Everything happens in single activity, logic is separated by fragments.

Comment: shall i use a sliderPanel or scrollview ?

Answer (score 1):

This article:

http://flavienlaurent.com/blog/2013/08/28/each-navigation-drawer-hides-a-viewdraghelper/

Literally describes how to do this

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with multitask? With two activities one above the other?

If that's what you are asking for you can use SlidingMenu library, this allows you tu insert another layout on the same activity that can be hidden, a sliding menu.

[SlidingMenu Lib](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu)

If you are asking for running a process outside UI thread you must use AsyncTask class. It provides an easy way of doing some work in a different thread.

[AsyncTask Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Answer (score 0):

All what i need is ViewDragHelper Class.
Here is the documentation.[enter link description here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/ViewDragHelper.html)